# implement length() of string without using Built-in functions

Tags: java, string

How can i get the length of a string in java without using any Built-in Functions
neither using length() nor using any function

Comment: You can't do anything without using any functions.

Comment: What have you tried? What did you research?

Comment: Count it by hand.

Comment: ...and _why_ do you need to do it like this? How are you going to get the length of a string without either directly calling `length` _or_ by retrieving its contents (which is also surprisingly a method)?

Comment: you can do stuff like ``theString.toCharArray​().length``, but that's just a complicated way of calling ``length()``. And ``toCharArray​()`` itself is a method..

Comment: pointless question. what's the point of having `length()` if you can't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You can serialize the string and examine the bytes.(although some other class will call a String's function.)

b) you can sent it to a Writer subclass where you implement the write(char[], int, int) (although, again, some other class will call a String's function.)

c) you can try to cheat and use reflexion to pull private fields, and setAccessible(true) on them, to pull the relevant fields. Watchout, this is JRE specific, so not portable across java version.